# Ubuntu 12.04 LTS stopped detecting BCM4312 on DELL E6500

Tags: 12.04, wireless, dell, broadcom

I have been using wireless seamlessly since I upgraded to Ubuntu 12.04 LTS. I did a botched attempt of installing **Octave 3.6**, at that time I was connected via Ethernet. I postponed that installation till later, but when I went home and tried to connect to a wireless network realized that Ubuntu is not detecting the wireless adapter..the blue light did not come up even after toggling hardware key. On booting into windows OS I was able to confirm that the adopter is working and I could connect to wireless network. Since then I have tried a number of things including re-installing **BCM** drivers as mentioned on other threads but nothing worked.

Here is the current status of my machine and wireless adapter....

```
 lspci -v 

0c:00.0 Network controller: Broadcom Corporation BCM4312 802.11b/g LP-PHY (rev 01)

Subsystem: Dell Wireless 1397 WLAN Mini-Card

Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 3

Memory at f69fc000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=16K]

Capabilities: <access denied>
Kernel modules: ssb

    lsmod

Module                  Size  Used by

ip6table_filter        12815  0 

ip6_tables             27864  1 ip6table_filter

iptable_filter         12810  0 

ip_tables              27473  1 iptable_filter

x_tables               29891  4 ip6table_filter,ip6_tables,iptable_filter,ip_tables

vesafb                 13844  1 

parport_pc             32866  0 

ppdev                  17113  0 

rfcomm                 42651  0 

lp                     17799  0 

parport                46562  3 parport_pc,ppdev,lp

bnep                   18139  2 

joydev                 17693  0 

bluetooth             205289  10 rfcomm,bnep

binfmt_misc            17540  1 

nfsd                  277884  2 

nfs                   356377  0 

lockd                  90326  2 nfsd,nfs

fscache                61568  1 nfs

auth_rpcgss            53380  2 nfsd,nfs

nfs_acl                12883  2 nfsd,nfs

sunrpc                241772  6 nfsd,nfs,lockd,auth_rpcgss,nfs_acl

psmouse                97485  0 

serio_raw              13211  0 

video                  19596  0 

compat                 20099  3 rfcomm,bnep,bluetooth

e1000e                156715  0 

    lshw -C network 

*-network UNCLAIMED

description: Network controller

product: BCM4312 802.11b/g LP-PHY

vendor: Broadcom Corporation

physical id: 0

bus info: pci@0000:0c:00.0

version: 01

width: 64 bits

clock: 33MHz

capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list

configuration: latency=0

resources: memory:f69fc000-f69fffff

    uname -a

Linux ubuntu 3.2.0-35-virtual #55-Ubuntu SMP Wed Dec 5 18:02:05 UTC 2012 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

    sudo modprobe wl
FATAL: Module wl not found.
```

Thanks in advance for any help.

- UPDATE

After trying the answer below:
    fsheikh@ubuntu:~$ sudo apt-get remove --purge bcmwl-kernel-source
    Reading package lists... Done
    Building dependency tree
    Reading state information... Done
    Package bcmwl-kernel-source is not installed, so not removed
    0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.

```
fsheikh@ubuntu:~$ sudo apt-get install firmware-b43-lpphy-installer 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
firmware-b43-lpphy-installer is already the newest version.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.

fsheikh@ubuntu:~$ sudo modprobe b43
WARNING: Error inserting bcma (/lib/modules/3.2.0-35-virtual/updates/cw-3.6  /bcma.ko): Unknown symbol in module, or unknown parameter (see dmesg)
WARNING: Error inserting cfg80211 (/lib/modules/3.2.0-35-virtual/updates/cw-3.6/cfg80211.ko): Unknown symbol in module, or unknown parameter (see dmesg)
WARNING: Error inserting mac80211 (/lib/modules/3.2.0-35-virtual/updates/cw-3.6/mac80211.ko): Unknown symbol in module, or unknown parameter (see dmesg)
FATAL: Error inserting b43 (/lib/modules/3.2.0-35-virtual/updates/cw-3.6/b43.ko): Unknown symbol in module, or unknown parameter (see dmesg)
```

Comment: Please see: http://askubuntu.com/questions/223900/why-has-wireless-disappeared-after-my-12-10-upgrade/223913#223913

Comment: Thanks chilli555... But after sudo modprobe wl ...I get FATAL: Error inserting wl (/lib/modules/3.2.0-35-virtual/updates/dkms/wl.ko): Invalid argument

Comment: Did you install the headers and re-install bcmwl-kernel-source?

Comment: Yes I did. Both command executed correctly just that there was a locale warning while reinstalling bcmwl-kernel-source. Nothing serious I guess, so I rebooted. Currently systems setting shows a bcm43 driver activated but not used. Reading elseware I also used synaptic to remove linux-backport-wireless-cw packages, and then I am back to square one.

Comment: Let's see: dmesg | grep -e wl -e b43. Also: lspci -nn | grep 0280.

Comment: dmesg | grep -e wl -e b43

Comment: Strangely, dmesg | grep -e wl -e b43...returned empty...while 'lspci' gave: 0c:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Broadcom Corporation BCM4312 802.11b/g LP-PHY [14e4:4315] (rev 01)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Never remember opting for virtual kernel with Ubuntu 12.04LTS. Coupled this with the fact that wireless was working before, I used synaptic to remove all virtual kernel headers, image and library packages. Guess what WiFI started working with no additional installation, etc. However it seems I have messed up my lightdm installation now but that is a subject for another thread.

Thanks chili555 for your help though.

Answer (score 0):

Please try, with a temporary ethernet connection:

```
sudo apt-get remove --purge bcmwl-kernel-source
sudo apt-get install firmware-b43-lpphy-installer
sudo modprobe b43
```

Reference: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1030503