# Wireless on HP Pavillion dv4 not working

Tags: wireless, hp

I have recently tried to install Ubuntu 12.10 x64 over x32 and it installed, but now the wireless won't work. I have a BCM 4312 card for the wireless. I've tried pressing the wifi button on the computer, but it just stays orange. Also, I've tried a lot of different things and "wl" is non existent on my computer. I'm still trying to get the hang of this, so please explain and help!

UPDATE: So, it turns out I just needed to update my kernel to 3.8. I followed the instructions found at this thread: [Why has wireless disappeared after my 12.10 upgrade?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/223900/why-has-wireless-disappeared-after-my-12-10-upgrade)

Comment: Please confirm the details of your wireless card from the terminal command: lspci -nn.

Comment: I think this is what you want: Network controller [0280]: Broadcom Corporation BCM4312 802.11b/g LP-PHY [14e4:4315] (rev 01)

Answer (score 0):

Please get a temporary wired ethernet connection and open a terminal and do:

```
sudo apt-get install linux-headers-generic
sudo apt-get install --reinstall bcmwl-kernel-source
sudo modprobe wl
```

You should be all set.

Comment: I tried that and get this:  Module build for the currently running kernel was skipped since the
kernel source for this kernel does not seem to be installed.

Comment: The installation of linux-headers is supposed to fix that. Please try: sudo apt-get install linux-headers-$(uname -r)  Then do the steps in my answer again. Let me know if there is a further error.

Comment: i'm having this precise issue with an ubuntu 20.10 install.
same notebook type, same wireless hardware (BCM4312) confirmed with the lspci command.

i wonder if those same steps are required?

Comment: @davecampbell I suspect not. Please start your own new question and we'll be happy to help.

Comment: it actually worked perfectly, but i followed the instructions here (kind of official,in a sense) - and your instructions appear to be consistent with these:
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/WifiDocs/Driver/bcm43xx

thanks for your attention!  ubuntu continues to get easier to deal with, and i appreciate people like you who can boil down a LOT of detail into the minimum commands.  that is valuable to many.